# SQL Server MAXDOP on VMWare Virtual Servers

Tags: sql-server, maxdop

When setting MAXDOP on VMWare virtual servers VMWare recommend following the Microsoft guidlines

https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi

- Keep MAXDOP at or below # of logical processors
- Keep MAXDOP at 8
- Keep MAXDOP at or below # of logical processors per NUMA node
- Keep MAXDOP at 8

A colleague argues that virtual CPUs are different, SQL Server can only access 1 CPU no matter how many you have and MAXDOP should be set to 1. Based on the above information and lots of other websites I think that is wrong, and bad for performance. I have set MAXDOP as above for years. But is there any truth in what they are saying.

Many Thanks

Comment: You are correct, he is wrong in saying that MAXDOP=1 would be good for all types of application and workload. `Sharepoint` and `DynamicsAX` are applications which MS suggests should have MAXDOP as 1 in database they are accessing, there may be others I am not aware about. For others you need to find out what is best for your environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your colleague is wrong. SQL Server will use parallelism whether the cores are virtual or not.

In fact the VMWare SQL Server best practices guide you link to explicitly states:

> There is a fair amount of misconception and incorrect advice on the
>   Internet regarding  the values of these configurations in a virtual
>   environment. When low performance is  observed on their database, and
>   CXPACKET is high, many DBAs decide to disable  parallelism altogether
>   by setting MAXDOP value to one (1). This is not recommended  because
>   there might be large jobs that will benefit from processing on
>   multiple CPUs.  The recommendation instead is to increase the CTFP
>   value from five seconds to  approximately 50 seconds to make sure only
>   large queries run in parallel. Set the  MAXDOP according to
>   Microsoft’s recommendation for the number of cores in the  VM’s NUMA
>   node (no more than eight).

I will however note that the writer of the VMWare best practices guide is confused. The value is not in seconds but in "cost" (also known as [query bucks](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/10/estimated-subtree-cost-query-bucks-no-really/))